# Buttons with image on IOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, button, uibutton

I have multiple buttons in an outlet collection with no image defined on any of them in the inspector.  I use a `for` loop and the following line of code to set the image on each button after each interaction.

```
[button setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
```

When the application starts in the simulator, some of the buttons have the image neatly fit in the button, the others have a tall, skinny version of the image.  If I understand how this works, at the beginning the code to set the image has not been executed.

How is the image being displayed at the beginning?
How do some buttons have the correct image and others are screwy?

Comment: Are the view sizes, images and content modes all the same?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your buttons may not be all using the same contentMode. Look at the view in interface builder and go to the attributes inspector and under "View" you should see a "Mode" drop down with values like "Scale to fill", "Aspect Fit", "Aspect Fill". You should make sure this value is the same for all your buttons. (Obviously use the value from whichever buttons are displaying the way you want). You can see what each mode option does here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: Good suggestion, akhalsa, but they all do have the same value.  I picked one that was off and tried various values and it didn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you don't have a background.

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The background image is scaled to fill the bounds, but the image is not.